# How do you combine useState + useEffect in Strict Mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook that allows you to generate a value once, and (optionally) clean it up on dismount:

```
function useConst(fn, cleanup) {
  const [value] = useState(fn);

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      cleanup?.(value);
    },
    [value]
  );
  return value;
}
```

This hook does not work in strict mode because the effect is run 2x.

I put together a sample, which includes the original hook, as well as `useRef` and `useMemo` varieties, but all of them fail in strict mode:

[Sample CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-dev-forked-rgxdjc?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)

Comment: I might be misreading this but isn't the whole point that `cleanup()` itself should also be idempotent? And if it isn't, that's not this code's problem.

Comment: No. This is in essence trying to do the same thing as `useEffect` with a setup/cleanup, but where we need to do the setup in sync and not at some later point. Consider React's [subscribe/unsubscribe example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-dev-4mdv9v?file=%2Fsrc%2Fchat.js).

Comment: I don't get what you aim here. if you don't change `value` at all, it is the `fn` from first render, right? then, you can just use `[]` as dependency array for `useEffect`.

Comment: @ilkerkaran the issue is just in dev strict mode, where state functions and effects are run 2x. If you check out the sample code, you can see the issue as soon as you force a render. I added the final working case.

Comment: @DavidS you urged my curiosity and I think you should take a look at https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm aware of how those details work, but it is nice to see they covered many of the common cases. I think the "resetting CSS animation" example most closely follows the scenario I ran into. In my case, I wanted to make sure I never returned `null`, but by checking the ref on each render, the desired outcome can be satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution with `useRef` + `useEffect`. The key is to assign the ref whenever it isn't set, and unassign at cleanup:

```js
function useConstStrict(fn, cleanup) {
  const value = useRef();
  if (!value.current) {
    value.current = fn();
  }
  useEffect(() => () => {
    cleanup?.(value.current);
    value.current = null;
  }, []);
  return value.current;
}
```

I think I actually prefer this to `useState`.